# Would DLL hijacking work with load-time linking?

Tags: malware, programming

I was wondering if DLL hijacking would work with all types of linking or just run-time linking. I hear that malware uses it and wanted to know how it works

Comment: I remember that hijacking frameworks used to hijack the DLL loading code system wide so the answer would be YES. http://madshi.net would be an example to that AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of linking: static linking and dynamic linking.  [DLL Hijacking](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/dll-hijacking/) is when a malicious program takes advantage of dynamic linking.  For dynamic linking to work there needs to be a list of paths to find the shared library that is being linked.  [In Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there are various ways for the search path to be affected.  But there is generally an order in how the search is performed, and most applications don't provide a fully qualified path (e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll`) for the shared object that they plan to load.

What happens is an attacker will place a DLL of the same name in a location searched before the location of the legitimate DLL.  For instance, lets say the search path when attempting to load `kernel32.dll` is first `C:\Program Files\MaliciousDir\` and then `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`.  The application simply calls `LoadLibraryW(L"kernel32.dll");`.

As long as the attacker has their version of `kernel32.dll` in `MaliciousDir`, their version will get loaded not the legitimate version.  This can be mitigated by providing a fully qualified path to the library you're loading.

---

Static linking means that the entire library was built into the application.  An entire copy is kept by the application, and all function addresses to that library are resolved at compile time.  Which means that there is no searching for the library, and an attacker can't replace the library itself.  The downside to this is that the application becomes enlarged by the size of the library, and updating the library itself means that the entire application needs to be updated.

In this case DLL hijacking does not work.